# onListItemClick is not working?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to set an OnItemClickListener with a custom adapter. The onItemClick is not firing when I press on.

I found that I need to add some attributes, but still doesn't work.

```
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
```

Activity:

```
public class StudentActivity {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private Student mStudent;

    private TextView mName;
    private Button mMonday;
    private ListView mListView;

    //That will be deleted
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    public StudentActivity(Activity activity, Student student) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mStudent = student;

        mName = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.name_student);
        mName.setText(mStudent.getFirstName() + " " + mStudent.getLastName());

        mListView = (ListView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        int numberOfIntervals = 7;

        List<String> hours = new ArrayList<>();
        hours.add("08:00-10:00");
        hours.add("10:00-12:00");
        hours.add("12:00-14:00");
        hours.add("14:00-16:00");
        hours.add("16:00-18:00");
        hours.add("18:00-20:00");
        hours.add("20:00-22:00");

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntervals; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
            temp.put("First", hours.get(i));
            temp.put("Second", "");
            list.add(temp);
        }

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(mActivity, list);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addListenerForMondayButton(adapter);
        addListenerForListViewItem(mListView);
    }

    private void addListenerForMondayButton(final ListViewAdapter adapter) {
        mMonday = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.name_monday);

        mMonday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ReservationTask reservationTask = new ReservationTask();
                reservationTask.populateList(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addListenerForListViewItem(ListView view) {
        view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                addNotification();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.arrow_back)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification")
                        .setContentText("This is a test notification");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mList;
    private List<Reservation> mReservationList;
    Activity mActivity;
    TextView mHour;
    TextView mName;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        mActivity = activity;
        mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

        mHour = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_hour);
        mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);

        HashMap<String, String> map = mList.get(position);

        mHour.setText(map.get("First"));
        boolean set = false;
        if (mReservationList != null && mReservationList.size() > 0) {
            for (Reservation reservation: mReservationList) {
                String createInterval = reservation.getStartHour() + "-" + reservation.getEndHour();
                if (createInterval.equals(parseTime(mHour.getText().toString()))) {
                    mName.setText("Dima");
                    set = true;
                }
            }
            if (set == false) {
                mName.setText(map.get("Second"));
            }
        } else {
            mName.setText(map.get("Second"));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public void populateNameReservation(List<Reservation> reservations) {
        mReservationList = reservations;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private String parseTime(String intervalTime) {
        String startHour = intervalTime.substring(0, intervalTime.indexOf("-"));
        String endHour = intervalTime.substring(intervalTime.indexOf("-") + 1, intervalTime.length());
        Time startHourTime = Time.valueOf(startHour + ":00");
        Time endHourTime = Time.valueOf(endHour + ":00");

        return startHourTime + "-" + endHourTime;
    }
```

XML layout for list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Text View"
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_hour"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Text View"
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: have you called your click method or not?

Comment: Try to add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" this line inside your parent layout, i.e., LinearLayout

Comment: did you call addListenerForListViewItem(listView) in your activity?

Comment: Please add more code in finding the problem

Comment: why is android:clickable="false"?? it should be "true"

Comment: I call the method. I made an debug and the method is registered but, when I press on the item, the click is not firing. I tried also to put "android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" but still doesn't work

Comment: If you are using any layout **inside** the list view ONLY use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants` and it should be in the **first** parent layout inside the listView

Comment: Please post you adapter code also

Comment: Added the entire code

Comment: How do you call `addListenerForListViewItem`

Comment: You better option RecyclerView instead of ListView check this : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: @Cosmin Dima If you have an active view/focusable view in your list view then it will disable `onItemClickListener`... you can try to make it unfocusable by adding:
`android:focusable="false"` to any view that is usually focusable. i think you are using those attributes on listview and thats the reason.use them properly

Comment: Doesn't work. I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code i have used a list view with a custom class for inflating data in list view and then one clicking list item redirecting to another activity using intent.

Check this out it is working code.

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            CustomList customList = new CustomList(TrainingProgrammes.this, listProgrms, reference_IDs, programStatus, _tierLevel, _tierIndexValue, programIDS);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(customList);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                    if (programStatus.get(i).equals("Subscribed")) {

                        System.out.println("Program id is trianing programme new : " + programIDS.get(i) + " CLIENT_ID " + _clientID);


                        Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskList.class);
                        nextScreen2.putExtra("EMAIL_ID", _loginID);
                        nextScreen2.putExtra("PROGRAMME_ID", programIDS.get(i));
                        nextScreen2.putExtra("CLIENT_ID", _clientID);
                        // nextScreen2.putExtra("PROGRAMME_STATUS", programStatus.get(i));
                        startActivity(nextScreen2);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Where did you copy that? He has no intents you can remove the whole if block